# Undefined symbols. ld: symbol not found

Tags: c++, linux, linker

Everything is working except this undefined symbols error:

```
bash-3.2$ make
g++ -Wall -g solvePlanningProblem.o Position.o AStarNode.o PRM.o PRMNode.o Worl.o SingleCircleWorld.o Myworld.o RECTANGLE.o CIRCLE.o -o solvePlanningProblem

`Undefined symbols:
  "Obstacle::~Obstacle()", referenced from:
      Myworld::~Myworld()in Myworld.o
      Myworld::~Myworld()in Myworld.o
      Myworld::~Myworld()in Myworld.o
  "RECTANGLE::RECTANGLE()", referenced from:
      Myworld::readObstacles(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&
in Myworld.o
  "CIRCLE::CIRCLE()", referenced from:
      Myworld::readObstacles(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&
in Myworld.o
  "typeinfo for Obstacle", referenced from:
      typeinfo for RECTANGLEin RECTANGLE.o
      typeinfo for CIRCLEin CIRCLE.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [solvePlanningProblem] Error 1`
```

It's such a strange error. Is something wrong with the constructor or destructor?
Any advice will help.

After adding {} after all constructors and destructors the error has been reduced 
to:

```
Undefined symbols:

  "vtable for Obstacle", referenced from:
      Obstacle::Obstacle()in Myworld.o
  "typeinfo for Obstacle", referenced from:
      typeinfo for RECTANGLEin RECTANGLE.o
      typeinfo for CIRCLEin CIRCLE.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: It’s hard to answer this without seeing any code. Did you provide implementations for these destructors etc.?

Comment: what's the implementation of the desctructor ?
i have done nothing in the ~Obstacle();

Comment: I think he's trying to compile something which ships a custom library .. and gcc is just not finding it (or building it) for whatever reason .. and the build is not breaking at the appropriate point.

Comment: What are the compile commands for the .cpp files?  It looks like you have typeinfo turned off when compiling the .o files, but not when building the final exe.  Do you have "no-rtti" in the compile commands?

Answer (score 11):

The linker can't find the destructor for the Obstacle class.

Is it in another object file (perhaps Obstacle.o)? If so, add that to the list of objects to link.

Is it supposed to be an empty virtual destructor within the class definition? In that case, make sure you've written

```
virtual ~Obstacle() {}
```

and not

```
virtual ~Obstacle();
```

The first implements the destructor; the second declares that it exists, but is implemented somewhere else.

Comment: I add {} in and the error is reduced to 
 "typeinfo for Obstacle", referenced from: typeinfo for RECTANGLE in RECTANGLE.o typeinfo for CIRCLEin CIRCLE.o 
ld: symbol(s) not found collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make:

Comment: See my answer to your other question.

Comment: This is a highly relevant point. I spent several hours trying to track down a "symbols not found in vtable" link error for a method in a templated class where the method was defined IN the header file -- impossible that the instantiated class/method wasn't getting compiled. The class also derived from a parent. It wasn't until I declared the destructors virtual (even though their bodies are empty) that this bug was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are missing the implementation of the desctructor `~Obstacle` that is anyway defined..

LD is the linker, this means that everything compiles fine but when it starts to link binaries into one it can't find the destructor for Obstacle used in your code..

Add

```
~Obstacle() {}
```

to your class definition in `.h` file, or if you prefer just define it `~Obstacle()` and provide implementation in `.cpp` file as `~Obstacle::Obstacle()`

Comment: can you tell me how to do the destruction ?
Class Obstacle is the base class with two sub-classes CIRCLE and RECTANGLE.

Comment: Ok, you should use a virtual destruction in your base class and implement it in subclasses. Could u please edit your question and add code? that would be helpful..

Comment: I have already the ~Obstacle(); in Obstacle.h. But still the problem

Comment: do you have it also in subclasses?

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you declared the D'tor but didn't implement it. Try to put {} in the .h file, or:

```
Obstacle::~Obstacle()
{
}
```

in the cpp.

Comment: what is the actural meaning of "typeinfo for Obstacle" and "vtable for Obstacle"

Comment: Lisa, these messages are regarding virtualization. The vtable is referring to the "virtual table", it's a table which holds the function addresses of an object in an inheritance tree, to know to which implementation to go (because of overriding and so on).
Take a look here: 
http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/125-the-virtual-table/
 Perhaps if you embed your code here I could be more helpful

Comment: You may have another virtual method which isn't implemented in a base class nor in its inheritants.
I would go over the code and check for un-implemented methods in your classes, probably in Obstacle and its inheritants.

Answer (score 0):

it also looks like the default constructors are missing from `RECTANGLE` and `CIRCLE`.

Comment: there are ~RECTANGLE and ~CIRCLE in both .h files. what do you mean by missing

Comment: It says that `RECTANGLE::RECTANGLE` is missing. That is the constructor, not the destructor. Same for CIRCLE.

Comment: as said above, all constructor and deconstructor have been modified and the error has been reduced to two problems

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a library. or have a broken tool chain (which depends on the include path for gcc).

Google turned up squat.. so clarifying what you are actually *trying* to build lets us help you more :)