# What should I do with this strange error?

Tags: c++

Everything is fine and the final problem is so annoying. Compile is great but link fails:

```
bash-3.2$ make
g++ -Wall -c -g Myworld.cc
g++ -Wall -g solvePlanningProblem.o Position.o AStarNode.o PRM.o PRMNode.o World.o SingleCircleWorld.o Myworld.o RECTANGLE.o CIRCLE.o -o solvePlanningProblem

**Undefined symbols:

"vtable for Obstacle", referenced from:
      Obstacle::Obstacle()in Myworld.o

"typeinfo for Obstacle", referenced from:
      typeinfo for RECTANGLEin RECTANGLE.o
      typeinfo for CIRCLEin CIRCLE.o

ld: symbol(s) not found

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

make: *** [solvePlanningProblem] Error 1**
```

Obstacle.hh

```
#ifndef Obstacle_hh 
#define Obstacle_hh

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Obstacle{
public:
    Obstacle(){}
    virtual bool collidesWith(double x,double y);
    virtual void writeMatlabDisplayCode(std::ostream &fs);
    virtual ~Obstacle(){}
};
#endif
```

What's the problem I have ? I can post any code you need to analyze it.

Comment: Do you have an `Obstacle` class, if so which source files have definitions for its member functions?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693634/undefined-symbols-vtable-for-and-typeinfo-for

Comment: yes, Class Obstacle is the base class with two sub-classes CIRCLE and RECTANGLE. they all have two common virtual functions

Comment: @Amro, ye, i ask again since i tried some methods they provided but the error is still here

Comment: Please post the code for the file that contains the `Obstacle` class definition and and source files that define member functions of `Obstacle`.

Comment: Please post the files where `Obstacle::Obstacle()` and `Obstacle::~Obstacle()` are defined.

Comment: actually i just add {} after them and do nothing

Comment: must i have a Obstacle.cc file ?

Comment: just in Obstacle.hh I update them.

Comment: OK, then please post the `Obstacle.hh` file _that you are actually using_.

Comment: i used virtual in the deconstructor and { }after them

Comment: OK, given that your constructor and destructor are inline, the compiler is probably going to look to place your typeinfo and vtable for `Obstacle` in the object file that contains one of your non-inline virtual functions. Which source file are `Obstacle::collidesWith` and `Obstacle::writeMatlabDisplayCode` defined in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You declare a non-abstract class `Obstacle`, but you don't implement all its member functions.

Better declare it as abstract class:

```
class Obstacle{
public:
    Obstacle(){} // this is superfluous, you can (and should) remove it
    virtual bool collidesWith(double x,double y) = 0;
    virtual void writeMatlabDisplayCode(std::ostream &fs) = 0;
    virtual ~Obstacle(){}
};
```

The reason is a heuristic you'll find in many C++ compilers - to avoid the needless creation of duplicate vtables and typeinfos for a class they are created when its first non-inline virtual member function (if it has one) is defined.

Your code foils this scheme: You include `Obstacle.hh` into some compilation unit, the compiler sees a class `Obstacle` that has `collidesWith` as first non-inline virtual member function, but it isn't defined in the current compilation unit, so the compiler thinks it can defer the creation of vtable and typeinfo for the class. Because there is no definition of `collidesWith`, they both end up missing when the program is linked.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you are missing and object file or library.  The one which defines and declares the Obstacle object.

A good place to look for that is in the header files (*.h) files referenced in  Myworld as this will give you an idea of what cpp/libraries (typically with the same name) are underlying the objects used by Myworld.

Edit, given Lisa's reply:
No, you do not need to add any *.hh files in the source code.  The problem is at link-time, not compile-time.
Isn't there an Obstacle.cpp file somewhere?  This would need to be compiled and the corresponding .o files would need to be added to the last gcc line in the make.

Bingo!  Upon seeing Obstacle.hh
These two virtual Methods are not pure virtual, and hence the compiler expects them to be defined somewhere, somehow.  And also the constructor and destructor are not defined. 
The easiest would probably be to write something like:

```
class Obstacle{
public:
    // Obstacle();
    virtual bool collidesWith(double x,double y) = 0;  // = 0 makes them pure virtual
    virtual void writeMatlabDisplayCode(std::ostream &fs) = 0;
    //~Obstacle();
};
```

Alternatively you could declare a small do-nothing constructor and destructor or you could make the destructor [pure] virtual to force the derived classes to implement a destructor...

Comment: in myworld,
 #include "World.hh"
#include "Obstacle.hh"
#include "CIRCLE.hh" 
#include "RECTANGLE.hh" is included
is there something wrong with this since RECTANGLE and CIRCLE are sub-classes of Obstacle. should i include "CIRCLE.hh" and "RECTANGLE.hh"?

Comment: i don't have a Obstacle.cc and the Obstacle.o because i think it's unnecessary since obstacle.hh has nothing but some virtual function and constructor

Comment: Can you post Obstacle.hh (or relevant snippets from it)?

Comment: yea, this really make sense but do these two virutal funciton related to the "typeinfo for Obstacle" error?

Answer (score 2):

The class Obstacle needs a virtual destructor.  Change the destructor definition to be:

```
virtual ~Obstacle();
```

The definition of a destructor also creates the vtable for a class with virtual functions.  It also ensures that a delete of a derived class instance through a base class pointer does the right thing.

Comment: +1, anyway it is vital for class with virtual methods. Another question is you need implementation.

Comment: @Roman Nikitchenko: It's not _vital_ for classes with virtual methods. It's only essential if you are going to be deleting derived classes through pointers to this base class. It is a common alternative to make base class destructors protected and non-virtual.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to link in the object file that contains the definition of Obstacle. The programs compile correctly because they included the prototypes, but at link-time, there is no matching symbol for the prototypes.

Comment: Obstacle is just a base class for RECANGLE and CIRCLE. so i just include "Obstacle.hh" in myworld.hh. is that ok

Comment: It is not ok. You need real definitions.

Comment: how can i do the real definition?