# undefined reference to `typeinfo for class'

Tags: c++, g++, linker-errors, virtual, typeinfo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [g++ undefined reference to typeinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307352/g-undefined-reference-to-typeinfo)
>   [Undefined symbols “vtable for …” and “typeinfo for…”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693634/undefined-symbols-vtable-for-and-typeinfo-for)

I can't use my class.

```
class Accel {
public:
    virtual void initialize(void);
    virtual void measure(void);
    virtual void calibrate(void);
    virtual const int getFlightData(byte);
};
class Accel_ad : public Accel {
public:
    Accel_ad() : Accel(){}
    void initialize(void) {/*code code code...*/}
    void measure(void) {/*measure code*/}
    const int getFlightData(byte axis){/*getting data*/}
    void calibrate(void) {
        int findZero[FINDZERO];
        int dataAddress;
        uint8_t  data[2];
        for (byte calAxis = XAXIS; calAxis < ZAXIS; calAxis++) {
            if (calAxis == YAXIS) dataAddress = 0x32;
            if (calAxis == XAXIS) dataAddress = 0x34;
            if (calAxis == ZAXIS) dataAddress = 0x36;
            for (byte i=0; i<FINDZERO; i++) {
                readReverseWordI2C(dataAddress,data);
                findZero[i] = (data[1] << 8) | (data[0]);;
                Delay_ms(10);
            }
            accelZero[calAxis] = findMedian(findZero, FINDZERO);
        }

        // replace with estimated Z axis 0g value
        accelZero[ZAXIS] = (accelZero[XAXIS] + accelZero[PITCH]) / 2;
        // store accel value that represents 1g
        measure();
        accelOneG = -accelData[ZAXIS];
    }
```

main.cpp

```
Accel_ad accel;//all ok
accel.initialize();//all ok
accel.calibrate();//ERROR: undefined reference to `typeinfo for Accel'
accel.measure();//All okey
```

Who know what's wrong?

The entire error I get is:

> .\obj\main.o:(.rodata._ZTI8Accel_ad[typeinfo for Accel_ad]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Accel' [cc] collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Post the *exact* full compilation error.

Comment: [cc] ..\obj\main.o:(.rodata._ZTI8Accel_ad[typeinfo for Accel_ad]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Accel'
       [cc] collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @wsevendays: please update the question with the exact error message. In general, respond to requests for clarifications by updating your post, rather than replying with a comment. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a QA & site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You must either provide a definition for virtual functions in your base class or declare them pure:

```
class Accel {
public:
   virtual void initialize(void) = 0;        //either pure virtual
   virtual void measure(void) = 0; 
   virtual void calibrate(void) {};          //or implementation 
   virtual const int getFlightData(byte) {};
};
```

Comment: I found that if I comment line "measure();" my code compiles, but why I can't call function "measure();" from class itself?

Comment: @wsevendays is the problem with measure or calibrate?

Comment: At the end of function calibrate I call measure function, but my code fails.

Comment: @wsevendays have you tried what I wrote in my answer?

Comment: hmm..you answer right, but what you mean by "virtual void initialize(void) = 0; "?

Comment: But now my program fails to run. HardFault handler handles it.

Comment: @wsevendays it's an abstract(or pure) virtual method. It also makes the class abstract. You should google it, a comment box is not nearly big enough to fully explain what it means, and it is a very important concept in C++. I take it it worked?