# undefined reference to `vtable for a template

Tags: c++, templates, virtual

I have a template class which inherits from an interface class and therefore has virtual functions

```
//abstract.h
class Abstract {
virtual void abc();
Abstract();
}
//Abstract.cpp
Abstract::Abstract()
{ //do some init}

//concrete.h
class Impl {
public:
    void abcImpl();
};

template<typename T>
class Concrete : public Abstract, public T {
virtual void abc();
};
template<typename T>
Concrete<t>::abc()  { static_cast<T>(*this).abcImpl(); }

//concrete.cpp
void Impl::abc() { std::cout << "abc"; }
```

Used here

```
//foo.cpp
Concrete<Impl> *var1 = new Concrete<Impl>();
```

At link time, I get an error
 undefined reference to `vtable for Abstract'

In the past this error indicated that the complier couldnt find a place to put a vtable because there was no cpp file associated with that class. In other words, it puts the vtable where it first finds the first non-virtual definition of any member function.
But this is puzzling because.
1. Im not sure why it complains about Abstract - Abstract actually has a cpp
2. Maybe error msg actually means Concrete? But Concrete cannot be in a cpp file because its templatized.
So how does in general resolve this issue when dealing with a template class that also has virtual functions?

Comment: Is this the actual code? `Concrete` is not derived from `Abstract`. Note `Abstract::abc()` is not a pure `virtual` function and therefore must be defined.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined symbols "vtable for ..." and "typeinfo for..."?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693634/undefined-symbols-vtable-for-and-typeinfo-for)

Comment: For me it was @hmjd 's note.

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be due to the `abc()` method not declared as pure virtual. For example, GCC will use `abc()` as the key method for vtable placement, because it is the first non-inline, non-pure virtual method declared in the class (details: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vague-Linkage.html). If you declare `abs()` pure virtual, it should place vtable in Abstract.cpp where the constructor is defined.