# unable to load, undefined symbol C++ name mangling

Tags: c++, extern

I get the following error when executing my program:

> E:Unable to load libsim.so: libsim.so: undefined symbol: _ZTV15IteratorRegFile

in sim.cpp there is s.th. like

```
//IteratorRegFileIs is a wrapper that calls the constructor for IteratorRegFile
Fwk::Ptr<IteratorRegFile> iteratorRegFile_ = IteratorRegFile::IteratorRegFileIs( "RF" );
void init(){
  SparseArrayInt64 *sparse_array = new SparseArrayInt64(segID);
}
```

in SparseArrayInt64.cpp:

```
extern Fwk::Ptr<IteratorRegFile> iteratorRegFile_;
```

IteratorRegFile.h:

```
public:
  static IteratorRegFile::ValidPtr IteratorRegFileIs(Tac::Name _name) {
    IteratorRegFile * m = new IteratorRegFile(_name);
    m->referencesDec(1);
    return m;
  }
protected:
   IteratorRegFile( const IteratorRegFile& );
   explicit IteratorRegFile(Tac::Name _name): Tac::Entity(_name),
     index_(0) {
    handleInit();
   }
```

Any idea why the compiler is mangling the function so the lib doesn't find it anymore?

Comment: Eh, one is a `Fwk::Ptr<IteratorRegFile>`, the other is a `IteratorRegFile` -- why _should_ the definition of one satisfy the other?

Comment: Is the '_' on the end being used consistently?

Comment: @stark yes its used consistently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this on Linux with gcc:

According to c++filt `_ZTV15IteratorRegFile` is `vtable for IteratorRegFile`. So the mangled name refers to vtvable, not your function.

I did some search and found this advice `"You must implement virtual methods of your class because that's when the compiler actually generates the vtable for it."`

You can check what symbols there are in a module in this way: 
`nm your-module-name`

I guess this links might help:

- [Undefined symbols "vtable for ..." and "typeinfo for..."?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1693634/184968)
- http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-development/2003/Sep/msg00273.html

Comment: thanks, but I am still not able to solve the issue as IteratorRegFile() seems to be implemented. I have added some more code.

Comment: thanks after some more work this solved my problem. I removed the explicit and created a separate implementation of the constructor