# compile cython with C++ class and get undefined symbels

Tags: c++, cython

I tried to wrap a C++ class with cython, it compiles ok, but when I import the extension, I ge t

```
ImportError: ./svd.so: undefined symbol: _ZTI5model
```

Here is the C++ header files:

first, the "model.h", model is the base class of svd.

```
// model.h
#ifndef MODEL_H_
#define MODEL_H_

#include "common.h"
#include "Data.h"
class model {
protected:
    Data data;
public:
    model(Data& data);
    virtual float predict(uint uid, uint mid);
    // evaluate using testset and return final RMSE
    virtual float evaluate();
    // put predictions to file
    void output(string filename);
    virtual void onestep();
    virtual ~model();
};

#endif /* MODEL_H_ */
```

then the svd.h, svd inherits from model.

```
// svd.h
#ifndef SVD_H_
#define SVD_H_
#include "../common.h"
#include "../model.h"
#include "../Data.h"
#define K_NUM 50

namespace SVD{

class svd : model {

public:
    svd(Data &data);
    void init(uint max_step, float alpha1, \
              float alpha2,  float beta1, float beta2); 
    float predict(UidType uid, ItemType mid);
    float evaluate();
    void onestep();
    ~svd();
}; // end class svd

void initModel(uint max_step, float alpha1, float alpha2,  float beta1, float beta2);

};// end namespace svd

#endif /* SVD_H_ */
```

last, the pyx file

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = ../model.cpp ../models/svd.cpp ../common.cpp ../Data.cpp ../model.cpp

cdef extern from "../models/svd.h" namespace "SVD":
    cdef cppclass svd:
        pass
```

and my setup.py file

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(
   ["svd.pyx"],                 # our Cython source
   language="c++",             # generate C++ code
))
```

I think the Symbol "model" may be svd's base class,

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide an implementation for the virtual methods in the base class or (if the class is supposed to be abstract) declare them as pure. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693634/undefined-symbols-vtable-for-and-typeinfo-for).