# virtual function in c++ need an implemetation without implemetation its giving an error

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
public:
  int a;
  virtual void fun();
};

int main(){A obj;}
```

getting error undefined reference to 'vtable for A'.
I want to know why without implement virtual function giving this type of error.

Comment: Are you confusing virtual functions with *pure* virtual functions?

Comment: Because that's how the language works. What are you trying to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652198/difference-between-a-virtual-function-and-a-pure-virtual-function

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Even if `fun` was a pure virtual function, the code would fail to compile as one can not instantiate abstract classes.

Comment: If you're asking why it's an error, that's because the language requires that all non-pure virtual destructors have definitions. If you're asking why you get that particular error message, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693634

Comment: @Joachim, absolutely. I was only wondering why the questioner is expecting a unimplemented function to leave the compiler unfazed.

Comment: but it is fine look at http://ideone.com/ToorYk may be your compiler is very old?

Comment: @RupeshYadav.: It's not fine. There's no requirement to diagnose the error, so the program might, or might not, compile, as long as it doesn't call the missing function. It looks like, with optimisation enabled, GCC eliminates the unused object, so that the missing vtable etc. aren't needed.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, Yes you are right, it is not working in vc++, see http://rextester.com/live/HEIK81240

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are declaring the function (whether it would be normal member function or virtual function) but you are not defining it anywhere..!!

You can try this way, so that it would compile and run fine.!

```
class A{ public:int a; virtual void fun(){}; };

int main(){ A obj; }
```