# symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: _ZN7QPixmap16fromImageInPlaceER6QImage6QFlagsIN2Qt19ImageConversionFlagEE

Tags: qt, runtime-error, qpixmap

Good afternoon, I'm creating a project in Qt C ++ on Linux, and the computer where I am creating works properly, but over the executable from the computer to another tells me the following error when run:

***./Agenda: Symbol lookup error: ./Agenda: undefined symbol: _ZN7QPixmap16fromImageInPlaceER6QImage6QFlagsIN2Qt19ImageConversionFlagEE***
Any idea, thank you very much.

Comment: Symbol `QPixmap::fromImageInPlace(QImage&, QFlags<Qt::ImageConversionFlag>)` is missing. The computer could not have the correct version of qt library your application required?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, the program is created with Qt 5.4.1 and both computers have Qt4 libraries and QT5.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, I had slightly different method signatures in the header and source file (a missing const keyword). The compiler did not throw an error but the program crashed at runtime with a similar error as yours.

Fixing the signature and a clean recompile afterwards solved the problem.

It could also mean that the symbol is declared but not implemented - e.g. when the compiler did not include all source files.

Or it could be caused by non-pure virtual functions which are not implemented (for example if I forget to make them pure virtual in an interface, the compiler still looks for an implementation): See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1693787/3997725).

To check if the symbol is defined in your shared library or binary you can run this command:

```
nm -C <executable/shared lib> | grep ImageConversionFlag
```

Where "ImageConversionFlag" is a substring of the missing symbol in your error message.