# Assigning and using public variables in a class

Tags: c++

I have a class ABC in C++ .h class file.

.h file

```
#ifndef ABC_H_
#define ABC_H_

class ABC
{
  public:
    int x;
    int y;
};
#endif
```

.cpp file

```
//----- Empty  -----------
```

Main program .cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ABC.h"
using namespace std;
    int main() {
      ABC a1;
      a1.x=5; a1.y=2;
      cout<<a1.x;
      // ...
    }
```

Error during compiling in Eclipse:

```
symbols not found for architecture x86_64

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [CPPProgram] Error 1
```

All the other hello world programs etc. compile and run fine. I remember facing this error coming when I did the definition and implementation in separate files while using templates (and it went away when I implemented the definition and the implementation in same file)

I am not sure about what's wrong here. Any suggestions?

Comment: you should initialize a1 or declare it to be a struct. `ABC a1 = ABC();`

Comment: @Hans huh? What book did you read?

Comment: do you #include the .h file in your .cpp file?

Comment: @Hans: That will have no effect on the debugger complaint.

Comment: I added a `;` in the end of your class definition. I hope that was a type in the question.

Comment: @Hans:  1) Declaring it as a `struct` has no effect whatsoever except changing the default access descriptor.  2) `ABC a1;` and `ABC a1 = ABC();` are identical in this case.

Comment: @JohnDibling in this case, **they are not identical**. `ABC a1 = ABC()` value-initializes the class.

Comment: could you please post all includes in your main as well as the complete error message?

Comment: Are you building a target for x64 architecture without having the correct run time libraries installed? Which symbols in particular is Eclipse complaining about?

Comment: Other programs run file. `ABC a; a.x = 5; a.y = 6` also compile fine but on doing `cout<<a.x`, the compilation stops

Comment: @Dennis: `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [CPProgram] Error 1`

Comment: Please put spaces in your code.

Comment: @user1372448 Can you compile this with gcc / clang directly? (Ie Get Eclipse out of the loop?) Also: Why not just use a struct?

Comment: @user1372448: As per your comment, it looks like it is the problem with `cout`. Have you tried `std::cout`??

Comment: @Ammar He has `using namespace std;` But again. Add spaces between your `cout` and `<<` and `a1.x;`

Comment: Just for information:  Your code compiles and runs, unmodified, on my Debian 6.0.5 Squeeze stable x86_64 (amd64) machine.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Quite right.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693471/undefined-symbols-ld-symbol-not-found. It seems similar. Not sure why it would have a problem with your code though. It seems like a properly defined class... so as suggested it may be your std libs.

Comment: Compiles and links fine for me as well (with both gcc and VC++). Perhaps (despite the `.cpp` extension) Eclipse is using `gcc` instead of `g++` to do the building? That usually results in odd errors about unresolved symbols, even though the code is perfectly fine.

Comment: Just curious, why does the empty `.cpp` file exist? Could you try adding something to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code you posted, you are missing a semi-colon:

```
class ABC
{
public:
int x;
int y;
};
 ^
```

Comment: That was a typo while I wrote here directly.

Comment: @user1372448 then make sure you post a minimal example of actual code that reproduces the problem. For example, the includes in program.cpp.

Comment: Added the include files in the post

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you are including the right header file into your `.cpp` file. There might be another `ABC.h` file in your include path. You might also see if the file was named correctly on your file system (such as `abc.h` vs. `ABC.H`). You can test if your header file is getting included modifying the name of your type to something unique, and see if the compilation behavior changes.

It was pointed out to me that the compiler is supposed to use conventions in its header file inclusion guards that will not conflict with ordinary source files. Make sure none of your header files define names that use double underscore (`__`), or begin with an underscore that is followed by a capital letter.

In your comment, you list more information about compilation stopping on a line of code (you don't give the compilation error for why the compilation stops), and you added information about a link failure. The compiler is not supposed to leave partially created object files that would cause the linker to fail. Perhaps the linker is finding an older object file or a source file name conflict of some sort (eg, `test.c` and `test.cc` would both want to leave an object file named `test.o` usually). Direct your compilation system to remove all object files (whatever the equivalent of `make clean` would be), and see if the problem persists. If so, check for file name conflicts.

Comment: Should a standard header's preprocessor symbols not each begin with an underscore, precisely to avoid such collisions?  (This is just a question.  I do not know the answer.)

Comment: Note also: `#pragma once` <--- No naming conflicts here :D

Comment: @thb: All names starting with an underscore followed by either another underscore or a capital letter are reserved for the implementation (i.e., you're not supposed to use them).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: +1. I wasn't seeing anything in my copy of the standard that compelled an implementation to use a particular convention, but I was only doing a quick scan (and my copy of the C++ standard is 9 years old).

Comment: @user315052: FWIW, §17.4.3.1.2/1: "Each name that contains a double underscore (_ _) or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase
letter (2.11) is reserved to the implementation for any use."